# Query to Select between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a start and end dates. I want to get the list of dates in between these two dates. Can anyone help me pointing the mistake in my query.

| SlNo | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 14/02/2023 |
| 2 | def | 14/02/2023 |
| 3 | efg | 14/02/2023 |
| 4 | fgh | 01/03/2023 |

Since the Date Column is a nvarchar, I'm converting it and then using it in my Query

```
Select * from Table where 
 (Convert(varchar(30),Date,103) >= Convert(varchar(30),getdate()-30,103)
and  Convert(varchar(30),Date,103) <= Convert(varchar(30),getdate(),103))
```

the above query should be listing all the records in my table. However it results in 0 records. I tried using the between which results the same

Please advise

Comment: So you're converting `nvarchar` to `varchar`? What do you think that does? Why is your date stored as an `nvarchar` in the first place? Fix _that_ problem and it will magically fix all of your other current problems with this column (and will prevent future ones, too).

Comment: You probably want Select * from Table where 
 Convert(DATE,Date,103) >= getdate()-30
and  Convert(DATE,Date,103) <= getdate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the column. Never store a date as a string.

In the meantime, your problem is you're converting a string to a slightly different string. This still means you're comparing, say, the *string* `N'03/12/2022'` and expecting it to be less than `'01/01/2023'`.

Instead, try:

```
DECLARE @today date = getdate();

SELECT
...
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, [Date], 103) >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, @today)
  AND TRY_CONVERT(date, [Date], 103) <= @today;
```

Then fix the column. In case I didn't mention it before, **never store a date as a string.**

Lots more on best practices with date/time here (including why we shouldn't say `getdate()-30`):

- [Dating Responsibly](//sqlblog.org/dates)